# "want to know exactly that following"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Who's the president?*

*This would be an unusual question to ask in most countries, but in Venezuela many want to know exactly that following the dramatic events of 23 January.*

https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-36319877

I am not sure how to understand the passage in bold. Is "following" adjective or noun? "Many in Venezuela want to know that…" That = who is president? If so, why is the comma missing after "that"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**That**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/that) is a pronoun in your quote. It works exactly the same way as in this example:

> — What do you want? Do you want to know how much money I make a month?
>
> — I want to know exactly **that**! *(meaning: that's exactly what I want to know)*

In your quote, it refers to the question they posed just a line earlier: "who's the president?". I don't know much about the current political situation in Venezuela, but from what I understand, it sounds like after the years of political turmoil in that country, there are right now two presidents in office there. That's why "who's the president?" would be an unusual question to ask in a normal country because a country can't have two ruling presidents. And that's exactly what many people in Venezuela would like to know: "Hey, it'd be kind of cool if we knew who our president was. Is it this guy or that other guy?".

[**Following**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/following) is a preposition. The Oxford Dictionary says that *following* when used as a preposition can mean *coming after* or *as a result of*. Here's the example sentence they've got on their website:

> Police are hunting for two men **following** a spate of robberies in the area. *(police's hunting for two men comes after a spate of robberies in the area)*

And now your quote again with two parenthetical remarks expanding on the two points that I just made:

> This would be an unusual question to ask in most countries, but in Venezuela many want to know exactly that **(that which would be an unusual question to ask in most countries and that which many people in Venezuela really want to know: who is the president?)** following **(after)** the dramatic events of 23 January.

I think it's actually possible to place a comma before the preposition *following*. Maybe, that way, the sentence will read even easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could understand **following...23 January** as a participle clause. It expresses the context for the assertion in the main clause, that many people want to know who the president is. It could be placed before that clause:

> Following  the dramatic events of 23 January,  many in Venezuela want to know exactly that.

or after it:

> Many in Venezuela want to know exactly that, following  the dramatic events of 23 January.

The meaning could be paraphrased "as a consequence of".

Compare:

> Many citizens plan to vote early, anticipating long queues later in the day.
>
> Anticipating long queues later in the day, many citizens plan to vote early.